# Fast square of a row-stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to implement the square $M^2$ of a row-stochastic matrix $M$. Running time is critical. Are there any known algorithms that exploit the special nature of $M$ and are faster than the usual matrix multiplication algorithms?

Comment: in general, I don't think that nature of M is helpful. But if you have access to parallel computing systems, then lot of things can be done regarding matrix multiplication itself.